# Read passive tags with iOS and android device

Tags: android, ios, nfc, rfid

Is possible to read **passive RFID** tags with a iOS and android smartphone?

I would need to read a tag up to a dozen meters away to function as an anti-theft.

Is it possible with this type of tag without using additional hardware components?
Or are there other types of tags that can be read with the smartphone from distances over 5 meters and without the use of additional hardware?

I found several guides but using NFC technology (usable up to 10 cm away) or expensive additional hardware.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may consider iBeacon devices for your purpose. It works for both iOS and Android devices.

Comment: iOS 11 can read NDEF tags on an iPhone7 or later, but I suspect that the read distance is going to be a few cm at most; reading passive tags at long range requires large antennas, not the sort of thing that can be built into a smart phone

Comment: All clear. Thank you. I think at this point the best option will be to use the beacon as suggested by @AravindBhuvanendran

Answer (score 0):

No.

Android NFC only supports ISO 14443 and ISO 15693. Both of which have limited read distance. ISO 14443 a few centimeters, 15693, a meter or two.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_15693

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_smart_card